# Meaning of SPARQL operator ';'

Tags: sparql

What does ';' operator in WHERE clause means in SPARQL?

For example:

```
SELECT ?x ?y
WHERE { ?z foaf:name ?x ; :surname ?y }
```

What the ; operator means here? Is like a logical and that means this part

> ?z foaf:

goes before :surname again?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

It's not a SPARQL operator, but rather part of the syntax for triple patterns in SPARQL.  The full specification is in section [4.2 Syntax for Triples](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#QSynTriples) from the SPARQL spec.  Subsection **4.2.1 Predicate-Object Lists** describes the `;` notation:

> Triple patterns with a common subject can be written so that the
>   subject is only written once and is used for more than one triple
>   pattern by employing the ";" notation.
>
> ```
> ?x  foaf:name  ?name ;
>     foaf:mbox  ?mbox .
> ```
>
> This is the same as writing the triple patterns:
>
> ```
> ?x  foaf:name  ?name .
> ?x  foaf:mbox  ?mbox .
> ```

You might also be interested in subsection **4.2.2 Object Lists**:

> If triple patterns share both subject and predicate, the objects may
>   be separated by ",".
>
> ```
> ?x foaf:nick  "Alice" , "Alice_" .
> ```
>
> is the same as writing the triple patterns:
>
> ```
> ?x  foaf:nick  "Alice" .
> ?x  foaf:nick  "Alice_" .
> ```
>
> Object lists can be combined with predicate-object lists:
>
> ```
> ?x  foaf:name ?name ; foaf:nick  "Alice" , "Alice_" .
> ```
>
> is equivalent to:
>
> ```
> ?x  foaf:name  ?name .
> ?x  foaf:nick  "Alice" .
> ?x  foaf:nick "Alice_" .
> ```

The same syntax is used in Turtle and N3 serializations of RDF.  See [2.3 Abbreviating groups of triples](http://www.w3.org/TeamSubmission/turtle/#groups) for Turtle, which says

> The , symbol may be used to repeat the subject and predicate of triples that only differ in the object RDF term. …  The ; symbol may be used to repeat the subject of of triples that vary only in predicate and object RDF terms.

and for N3, see the [Semantics](http://www.w3.org/TeamSubmission/n3/#semantics) section, which says:

> In property lists, the semicolon ; is shorthand for repeating the subject. In object lists , is shorthand for repeating the verb.