# RDF Turtle syntax - How to reduce code duplication?

Tags: syntax, rdf, rdfs, turtle-rdf

I am having the following valid Turtle Syntax:

```
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>.
@prefix sc: <http://education.data.gov.uk/def/school/School#>.
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>.
@prefix geo: <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos>.

<http://example.com/schools/#1000> a <http://education.data.gov.uk/def/school/School> . 
<http://example.com/schools/#1000> <http://education.data.gov.uk/def/school/establishmentName>    "Atherstone Early Years Centre". 
<http://example.com/schools/#1000> <http://education.data.gov.uk/def/school/establishmentNumber> "1000". 
<http://example.com/schools/#1000> <http://education.data.gov.uk/def/school/Address>  [<http://education.data.gov.uk/def/school/address1> "RATCLIFFE ROAD";     <http://education.data.gov.uk/def/school/postcode> "CV9 1LF"]. 
<http://example.com/schools/#1000> <http://education.data.gov.uk/def/school/establishmentType> "Nursery".
<http://example.com/schools/#1000> <http://education.data.gov.uk/def/school/districtAdministrative> "North Warwickshire".
<http://example.com/schools/#1000> <http://education.data.gov.uk/def/school/uniqueReferenceNumber> "2016".
<http://example.com/schools/#1000> geo:lat "52.5786677".
<http://example.com/schools/#1000> geo:long "-1.5420408".
```

I basically define a school object with `id#1000` and after that I add properties to it. I was wondering whether I can get rid off the `<http://example.com/schools/#1000>` definition before every attribute and in some way to enclose the attributes with brackets or something else. Any ideas?

Comment: You can use the `;` as in `s p1 o1 ; p2 o2 ; p3 o3`.  It's been described in the answer to another question, [Meaning of SPARQL operator ';'](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18214338/1281433).  The question's not exactly the same—it's asking what the syntax in SPARQL is for, and you're looking for the syntax in Turtle, but the syntax is shared between the two languages.  There's also `,` for multiple objects of the same predicate: `s p1 o1a, o1b ; p2 o2a, o2b, o2c ; p3 o3 .`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Semi-colon:

```
<http://example.com/schools/#1000>
  a <http://education.data.gov.uk/def/school/School> ;
  <http://education.data.gov.uk/def/school/establishmentName>    "Atherstone Early Years Centre" ;
  ...
  <http://example.com/schools/#1000> geo:long "-1.5420408" .
```