# Meaning of rdf:type in Turtle snippet from Hebeler et al.'s Semantic Web Programming?

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, foaf

I’m a beginner in Semantic Web, I know a bit about what RDF does. Can someone kindly explain to me the following statements obtained from the book semantic web programming, Specially the syntax with semicolon (for example, rdf:type foaf:Person; and foaf: family name "Web")?

```
@prefix rdfs:
<http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix foaf:
<http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/> .
@prefix admin:
<http://webns.net/mvcb/> .
@prefix owl:
<http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix xsd:
<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix rdf:
<http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix swp2:
<http://semwebprogramming.org/2009/ont/chp2#>.
< swp2:me>
rdf:type foaf:Person ;
foaf:depiction <http://semwebprogramming.org/semweb.jpg> ;
foaf:family name "Web" ;
foaf:givenname "Semantic" ;
foaf:homepage <http://semwebprogramming.org> ;
foaf:knows < swp2:Reasoner> , < swp2:Statement> , < swp2:
Ontology> ;
foaf:name "Semantic Web" ;
foaf:nick "Webby" ;
foaf:phone <tel:410-679-8999> ;
foaf:schoolHomepage <http://www.web.edu> ;
foaf:title "Dr" ;
foaf:workInfoHomepage
<http://semwebprogramming.com/dataweb.html> ;
foaf:workplaceHomepage
<http://semwebprogramming.com>
```

Comment: The snippet you've posted is not a complete valid snippet in any RDF syntax that I know of (I'm assuming this is an incomplete cut and paste from a Turtle sample or SPARQL query), without a complete valid example your question is not going to get a good answer and is liable to be closed

Comment: Ok i have edited and given the complete copy paste :)..

Comment: so 'rdf : type foaf:Person' means we are referring to a 'type' 'Person' from the RDF schema 'foaf'? –

Comment: @anders_reimer yes.  Your data (after the prefixes) begins with the subject `swp2:me`.  (It doesn't look like you posted exact code, but rather that you edited it. E.g., `< swp2:me>` doesn't look like a valid URI.  Are you sure that isn't actually `<http://…/me>` or something?

Comment: @Joshua, i copied the exact code from the textbook named semantic web programming. yap it's an example only, it's not a valid URI, rather they used the book's name to create an 'example' URI. They also represented 'semantic web' as a a foaf:person, you may have noticed..that too..

Comment: @anders_reimer I assume you mean [this page](http://books.google.com/books?id=rtcIFmXkysEC&lpg=PA42&ots=tVk_9c_-DK&dq=semantic%20web%20programming%20foaf%3Adepiction&pg=PA42#v=onepage&q=semantic%20web%20programming%20foaf:depiction&f=false)?  Yikes, there are some problems in that, but it also looks like some got introduced in copying and pasting.  E.g., you lost the underscore in `foaf:family_name`, and the formatting changed a lot.  It's worth noting that the pages around that example *do* describe what the RDF says, and points to a discussion of the Turtle format.

Comment: You really should have mentioned that this text is from a book in the first place.  It's almost certainly fair use to reproduce it like this to ask a question about it, but mentioning that it came from a book would allow people to get the context much more quickly.

Comment: yes..i should have done that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As revealed in the comments, but not in the original posting, this sample RDF in the Turtle serialization is taken from [*Semantic Web Programming*, page 42](http://books.google.com/books?id=rtcIFmXkysEC&lpg=PP1&dq=semantic%20web%20programming&pg=PA42#v=onepage&q&f=false).  There are some problems in the data with malformed URIs (e.g., `< swp:me>`), but the Google Books preview looks like it might be from a draft of the book.  I don't know if those problems are present in the final printed copy.

The authors actually point you to Chapter 3 for more information about different serialization formats, but in this case, you just need to learn about the `;` and `,` notation.
The Turtle serialization It's very similar to the SPARQL query syntax, so you might benefit from the answer to [Meaning of SPARQL operator ';'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18214338/1281433).  In short, these syntaxes let you write

```
<subject> <predicate> <object> .
```

for a triple.  Sometimes you have multiple triples with the same subject and predicate, in which case you'd have:

```
<subject> <predicate> <object1> .
<subject> <predicate> <object2> .
```

These syntaxes let you abbreviate this using a comma:

```
<subject> <predicate> <object1> , <object2> .
```

When you have multiple predicate-object pairs with the same subject, e.g.,

```
<subject> <predicateA> <object1> .
<subject> <predicateB> <object2> .
```

you can use a semicolon to abbreviate:

```
<subject> <predicateA> <object1> ;
          <predicateB> <object2> .
```

You can combine body of these abbreviations, too, so that you could turn

```
<subject> <predicateA> <object1a> .
<subject> <predicateA> <object2a> .
<subject> <predicateB> <object1b> .
<subject> <predicateB> <object2b> .
```

as

```
<subject> <predicateA> <object1a> ,
                       <object2a> ; 
          <predicateB> <object1b> ,
                       <object2b> .
```

If you fix the problems in the original data (malformed URIs) and the problems that arose from copy and paste problems (e.g., missing underscore in `foaf:family_name`), you'll end up with data like this:

```
@prefix swp2:  <http://semwebprogramming.org/2009/ont/chp2#> .
@prefix rdfs:  <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix foaf:  <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/> .
@prefix admin: <http://webns.net/mvcb/> .
@prefix owl:   <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix xsd:   <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix rdf:   <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .

swp2:me  a                      foaf:Person ;
        foaf:depiction          <http://semwebprogramming.org/semweb.jpg> ;
        foaf:family_name        "Web" ;
        foaf:givenname          "Semantic" ;
        foaf:homepage           <http://semwebprogramming.org> ;
        foaf:knows              swp2:Reasoner , swp2:Statement , swp2:Ontology ;
        foaf:name               "Semantic Web" ;
        foaf:nick               "Webby" ;
        foaf:phone              <tel:410-679-8999> ;
        foaf:schoolHomepage     <http://www.web.edu> ;
        foaf:title              "Dr" ;
        foaf:workInfoHomepage   <http://semwebprogramming.com/dataweb.html> ;
        foaf:workplaceHomepage  <http://semwebprogramming.com> .
```

It's clear to see that using the `;` and `,` abbreviations I discussed above, this document contains a bunch of triples whose subject is `swp2:me`.  This aligns with the authors' description, in which they wrote (page 45):

> These Semantic Web statements produced by the FOAF-a-Matic describe
>   the person, Semantic Web, and friends.  The statements form
>   relationships.  For example, the first grouping under `#me` declares
>   information regarding the owner, the Semantic Web.  The grouping of
>   statements provides information about the owner's name, telephone
>   number, and the like.

If you want to see all the triples explicitly, the N-Triples serialization, which puts one triple per line, is useful:

```
<http://semwebprogramming.org/2009/ont/chp2#me> <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/workplaceHomepage> <http://semwebprogramming.com> .
<http://semwebprogramming.org/2009/ont/chp2#me> <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/knows> <http://semwebprogramming.org/2009/ont/chp2#Reasoner> .
<http://semwebprogramming.org/2009/ont/chp2#me> <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/phone> <tel:410-679-8999> .
<http://semwebprogramming.org/2009/ont/chp2#me> <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/knows> <http://semwebprogramming.org/2009/ont/chp2#Statement> .
<http://semwebprogramming.org/2009/ont/chp2#me> <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/workInfoHomepage> <http://semwebprogramming.com/dataweb.html> .
<http://semwebprogramming.org/2009/ont/chp2#me> <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/depiction> <http://semwebprogramming.org/semweb.jpg> .
<http://semwebprogramming.org/2009/ont/chp2#me> <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/givenname> "Semantic" .
<http://semwebprogramming.org/2009/ont/chp2#me> <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/schoolHomepage> <http://www.web.edu> .
<http://semwebprogramming.org/2009/ont/chp2#me> <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/homepage> <http://semwebprogramming.org> .
<http://semwebprogramming.org/2009/ont/chp2#me> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/Person> .
<http://semwebprogramming.org/2009/ont/chp2#me> <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/title> "Dr" .
<http://semwebprogramming.org/2009/ont/chp2#me> <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/nick> "Webby" .
<http://semwebprogramming.org/2009/ont/chp2#me> <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/knows> <http://semwebprogramming.org/2009/ont/chp2#Ontology> .
<http://semwebprogramming.org/2009/ont/chp2#me> <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/family_name> "Web" .
<http://semwebprogramming.org/2009/ont/chp2#me> <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/name> "Semantic Web" .
```

Comment: so 'rdf : type foaf:Person' means we are referring to a 'type' 'Person' from the RDF schema 'foaf'?

Comment: thank you so much, this is really helpful.So we use 'swp2:me a foaf:Person' instead of 'rdf:type foaf:Person' ?

Comment: `a` is just an abbreviation for `rdf:type` that can be convenient.  In either case, you need a subject, predicate, and object.  The subject is `swp2:me`, the predicate is `rdf:type`, and the object is `foaf:Person`.  You can write that as `swp2:me rdf:type foaf:Person` or as `swp2:me a foaf:Person`. I've updated my answer now that we've  identified the source of the data.  Also take a look at the N-Triples serialization, as it shows exactly what the triples are, with no abbreviations.

Comment: awesome, accepting the answer..your answers point me to new tools and resources such as rdfcat and N-triples serialization.